# What would be a safe and practical way to copy a string as defined by this prompt in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

The purpose of this function is to copy a string into a "buffer" - essentially another string. However, the problem seems overly complicated than what would be practical.

```
"Copies at most n-1 characters of string in into the buffer pointed to by
 out. If n is reached, returns -2.  Otherwise, returns -1 for malformed
 input and 0 upon successful completion."
```

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int copyStringN(register char *in, register char *out, register int n){
  //Declarations
    int i; //Dummy index
    if(!in || !out) return -1;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
         *out++ = *in++;
    }
    *out = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
//Declarations
  char in[] = "I'm not trying to inject malicious code...\\x29A.";
  const int N = sizeof(in);
  char out[N];
  int err;

//Main execution
  printf("\nThis function will copy at most n-1 characters of string into\nthe buffer pointed to by out.\n\n");
  err = copyStringN(in, out, N);
  assert(!err);
  printf("%s\n", out);


  printf("\nPlease press enter to exit...");
  getchar();
  return 0;  
}
```

This general form was suggested, but it seems overly convoluted than what needs to be done. Why would `n` ever be reached? The execution should stop before `n`. Furthermore, wouldn't `N = sizeof(in)` match the length of the original string?

Personally, I would rather use a function closer to

```
int copyStringN(register char *in, register char *out)
{
 if((!in || !out) && (sizeof(in)<=sizeof(out))) return -1;
 else{
      while(*t++ = *from++);
      return 0;
 }
```

}

```
int main(void){
  //Declarations 
  char in[] = "I'm not trying to inject malicious code...\\x29A.";
  const int N = sizeof(in);
  char out[N];
  int err;

.
.
.
```

I believe it would have the same effect with less statements. Let me make this more of a question, how could I write a function that copies a string into another array with the protection defined in the prompt? Also, are the two programs that I presented somehow vulnerable in a way I don't recognize?

Constructive input is appreciated.

Comment: Why use `register`? In general, that keyword should be removed from all your C code.

Comment: That is because I was reading a fairly old book on C. In reality, as you pointed out, there is really no need to use it.

Comment: @Mlagma "Furthermore, wouldn't N = sizeof(in) match the length of the original string?" length of string in = 48 and size of string in = 49

Comment: @YuHao, `register` is not obsolete in C, in the contrary. It just doesn't do what you'd expect from its name. It is a contract with the compiler that you wouldn't take that address of such an object, and that it *may* be realized by the compiler without a "backup" in memory.

Comment: @JensGustedt I get your point, that seems an odd but reasonable way to use it. But personally I won't use it in this way either because it's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange thing in C.

char mole[] = "mole" is not the same as char *mole = "mole"

I just tried:

```
char *a1 = "mole";
char a2[] = "mole";
printf ("s1: %i s2:%i\n", sizeof(a1), sizeof(a2) );
```

a1 is a pointer, so 4 or 8 depending on the architecture. 
a2 is an array of size 5.

But you can convert a2 to a char* without warnings. But you loose the size.

Comment: That's what I figured. I'm aware that they were converted in my arguments, but I'm not determining the size in the function. So I believe my measurement in `main` is still valid. Right?

Comment: In main it is fine. But your function take char*. So the size is lost. That's why you pass is as an explicit argument n.

Comment: The pressing problem that I still see is in regard to how the function can be called. It works properly if N is passed as the argument, but what is someone passes a values such as 50? At that point, it is an issue.

Comment: You don't assume a malicious caller. The point is just the function can not use sizeof to know the maximum size of the destination. That's why you have to pass it.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested alternative will not work. `(sizeof(in)<=sizeof(out)` will always be `TRUE`, because you are comparing pointers (and not arrays), and they are the same size.

If you want to make safe string copy function, you **must always** pass output buffer length for size checking, and have means to inform user if input was too long for output.

**Edit:**

Since people have suggested to use `strncpy`, I will present safer alternative:

```
int len = snprintf(output, OUTPUT_SIZE, "%s", input);
if(len < 0 || len >= OUTPUT_SIZE) {
    // Failed, handle error
}
```

Comment: That is a good point, I missed that. A concern that I see is in regard to how the function is called. If for some reason a value other than N is passed, it will certainly cause issues.

Comment: Why the -1, if I may ask?

Comment: how is this better than strncpy?

Comment: @starmole Because `strncpy` will generate non-nul terminated string, if input is longer than output. `snprintf`will not.

Comment: @user694733 Is that question aimed at me?

Comment: @Mlagma it was aimed to whoever gave my answer -1.

Comment: Never mind, I thought you were referring to the -1 in my post. Just noticed you have a -1 on your answer. Wasn't me.

Comment: True in general. But his function does it just fine. And it is really not the issue or the thing op is confused about. Also printf is pretty much the worst solution. Why not just do dest[n-1] = 0;?

Comment: @starmole I fail to see how snprintf is "the worst solution". Problem with dest[n-1] = 0; is that it is very likely to be forgotten after the strnpy. Also, I think that issue op was confused was that why length needs to be passed to function, and I already answered that.

Comment: No use in fighting. Using printf rubs me the wrong way, just thinking about the amount of work it has to do to parse the format string. I thought I answered his sizeof confusion. And I thought that was the main point of his question. He is already writing his own stnrcpy (with other bugs too!). The first line of your answer was right and helpful. But the rest will just confuse things, that's why I put -1.

Comment: @starmole Fair enough. You are right in that my `snprintf` example doesn't really relate to what op asked.

Answer (score 1):

Fewer statements in your source does not necessarily imply that it is simpler to grasp. The `while` row in your alternative solution may work, but is doing too many things at the same time for my taste. You are writing code *first* for other human beings to read, *then* for a compiler to read.

I like for example making the `NULL` and `\0` checking explicit.

It is also unclear what you are trying to achieve with the `sizeof` comparison. Besides comparing size of pointers (instead of intended arrays?), I think you meant `||` instead of `&&`. If either pointer is `NULL` it is an error, whatever the size.

```
int copyStringN(char *in, char *out)
{
    if((in == NULL) || (out == NULL)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        while(*in != '\0') {
            *out++ = *in++;
        }
        *out = '\0';
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The compiled code is probably not going to be much different, only the source is more human readable in my opinion.

Then if there happens to be no `'\0'` in the `in` string you are going to have problems. I suppose this is the reason for having a length limit `n`.

```
while((*in != '\0') && (n-- > 0)) {
    *out++ = *in++;
}
*out = '\0';
```

Note that you would still be in trouble if `n` is greater than the size of your arrays and you miss a `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar interface is [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy). Perhaps the error modes will make more sense after you read the man page.

Comment: In any practical situations, I would immediately use it. However, the problem assumes no prior knowledge of library functions - just pure array manipulation.

Comment: Note that strncpy is **not** safe. It will not add `'\0'` ending, if input is longer than output buffer.

Comment: You asked, "why would n ever be reached?" I think any man page for strncpy will answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use strncpy to prevent buffer overflow. char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num ); Also, better to use strlen rather than sizeof. So, Even if the source string is greater than the destination buffer. It will protect the destination buffer from buffer overflow. I would use n as the maximum size of the destination buffer. And In fact make n = strlen(dest_buffer) -1. To accommodate '\0'.

Comment: I repeat: Note that strncpy is **not** safe. It will not add `'\0'` ending, if input is longer than output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

a basic strncpy would look like:

```
char *strncpy(char *d,const char *s,int n){int i=0;while(n--&&d[i++]=*s++);return d;}
```

but you could force a null byte at n-1

```
char *sstrncpy(char *d, const char *s, int n){
  int i=0;
  while(--n&&d[i++]=*s++);
  if(!n)d[i]=0;
  return d;
}
```